# Can tinyproxy support keep-alive

Tags: http-proxy

Could anyone let me know whether tinyproxy can support keep-alive? thanks a lot.

if not, are there any hints for us to implement it? thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

After read the code, and got that current tinyproxy cannot support keep-alive, but it is possible to support after do some changes.